# How I can fill the DropDownList in the page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, browser, html-select

I have a `DropDownList` and I want to check what language does the browser have and set the values in the dropdown accordingly.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string language = Request.UserLanguages[0].ToString().Substring(0, 2);

     drpAnrede.DataSource = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + language + ".xml");
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

I have the solution for this problem...

aspx:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpAnrede" runat="server" DataTextField="display" DataValueField="id">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmldata" runat="server"></asp:XmlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
```

c#:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string language = Request.UserLanguages[0].ToString().Substring(0, 2);

            //drpAnrede.DataSource = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + language + ".xml");
            xmldata.DataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + language + ".xml");
            drpAnrede.DataSourceID = xmldata.ID;
        }
```

Comment: There's no question inside.

Comment: his question is the title of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `DataBind()` on your dropdown list after you set the datasource, no?

As in:

[Databinding DropDown Control in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251985/databinding-dropdown-control-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the XML is Ok, you need to call

```
drpAnrede.DataBind();
```

after applying the datasource.